# AutoStart an app after device reboot in a rooted device

Tags: android-10.0, autostart, android-reboot

I want to open an app after reboot.
I have checked my code in android 10, 8, 8.1 but it's not working
is there any way to start an app after reboot successfully?

Answer (score 0):

is app installed on the root (/)?
in case you can't use **lucky patcher** for this and activate the app in the background whenever the phone turns on.

Comment: firstly thanks for your reply @Miguel, currently I am running the app on the non-root device but I will root the phone if needed.